# Como interromper um laço while

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com JFrame de uma farmácia. É uma questão da faculdade. No o operador do caixa entra com a quantidade X de produto que o cliente escolhe de uma lista de n produtos e depois com o valor unitário de cada produto que vale Y. Ao final o sistema deve mostrar o valor total da compra, multiplicando X * Y = ?. Esse código é simples de fazer e utilizando o terminal ou faço ele sem problemas. Um exemplo de como eu controlo o laço pelo terminal.

```
while (n == 0){
        System.out.printf("\nEscolha:\n\t1 - Inserir novo produto\n\t0 - Valor Total");
            k = input.nextInt();
            if(k == 1){
                System.out.println("Quantidade de produtos: ");
                    //recebe
                System.out.println("Valor unitário");
                    //recebe
                    valorFinal = valorFinal + (quantidade * valorUnitario);
            }
            if(k == 0){
                //qualquer coisa
                n++;
                //interrompe o laço e imprime o valor
            }
    }
```

Utilizando o JFrame ele não funciona assim, pois não tem como o usuário escolher a opção 1 ou 0. Nesse caso eu pensei em criar um botão [Adicionar Produto] e toda vez que ele fosse clicado o vendedor adicionaria os produtos e o valor unitário e quando ele clicasse no botão [Valor Final] o laço seria interrompido e o resultado seria mostrado.

```
int n = 0;
    double valorFinal = 0;

    while(n == 0){
        resposta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Cadastrar nova compra?");
        if(resposta == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            double qtdIten = Double.valueOf(jTextField1.getText());
            double valor = Double.valueOf(jTextField2.getText());

             valorFinal = (valorFinal + (valor * qtdIten));

        }
        else{
            jTextArea1.setText("Valor da compra: "+valorFinal);
            n++;
        }
    }
```

De forma bem amadora fiz essa tentativa com uma JOptionPane mas não deu certo.

Comment: um simples `break;` deve resolver

Comment: Sem um **[mcve]** não da pra ver como sua tela funciona. Então removi a tag JFrame porque não há nada relativo a isso na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que o que não está funcionando é que o `JOptionPane` está por cima da tela e você não consegue voltar para inserir novos valores.

O ideal seria você fazer o seguinte, quando o usuário clicar no botão adicionar você pega os valores (como fez dentro do `if` mesmo) e soma, em seguida você atribui `""` aos campos texto para limpar os campos. Ao invés do usuário clicar várias vezes no OK do `JOptionPane` deve clicar várias vezes no botão de adicionar.

Você pode inclusive ter um campo na tela onde já vai escrevendo o valor final atual.

Uma outra forma seria usar o `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` que mostra um campo de texto, assim o usuário poderia inserir os valores de X e Y diretamente no diálogo. Não é exatamente profissional, mas permitiria fazer a entrada de dados. Poderia fazer isso com um único comando `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` e os valores separados por espaço ou vírgula, ou chamar `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` duas vezes, uma para cada valor que deseja capturar.

Comment: Utilizando a `JOptionPane` para receber os valores ele funciona. Mas ai eu precisaria definir o tamanho do laço `While`. Eu queria deixar ele automático de forma que o operador guardaria`n` dados.

Comment: Ah sim. Veja, essa não é a forma de fazer um "sistema" apenas um aplicativo para praticar programação ok? Então, nesse contexto, você poderia colocar que se o usuário clicar em "cancel" (vai retornar null) isso serve para quebrar o laço, ou o usuário pode digitar "fim" como primeiro valor.

Comment: Foi o que eu pensei, colocar uma mensagem explicando. Caso queria terminar digite 0, por exemplo. Ai o `n` que controla o `while` receberia 1 e o laço seria interrompido. Ps.: Em um sistema complexo como isso seria resolvido? E sim é uma atividade para prática de programação, estou aprendendo JFrame usando NetBeans.